# How to make this class execute?

Tags: java, android, class, sockets

I've created a class that connects to a socket and accepts String messages, and placed it in my MainActivity java file.

But I'm not sure what to do to make this execute - i.e. should it start under OnCreate, or could I make it start with a button, etc?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         //stuff
    }

  public void main(String[] args)
    {
        //connect to socket
        //process incoming data
        //display incoming data
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to go out and read some Android tutorials.  There is no main function in Android, for starters.  Your question basically boils down to "I know Java but not android, how do I write an app", which is way too broad.

Comment: @Gabe, I understand now that there is no main function and I've learned how the Android Manifest declares where to start executing the application. My question is as much Java as it is Android Development in fact - in that I would like to know how I can implement my "main(String[] args)" code in the OnCreate method. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a main() function in your class, the activity should start with whatever is stated in OnCreate().

Comment: You should do all the creation and initialization of objects in the OnCreate() method. It's better not to use main at all.

Answer (score 0):

call this main() function in your onCreate() function. As in android, onCreate() is called first just like main() is called in C/C++.
Your onCreate() function will look something like this.

`@Override`

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

`main(args);`

`}`